# Wordpress search in modified post title

Tags: query, search

I'm using `the_title` filter to add custom taxonomy name in front of my post (product) title.
I would like to add this modified title to WP search query.
Could someone help me with this topic?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own search creating a file called search.php in your theme, there you can customize your search however you want.

and can be called with:

```
get_search_form();
```